# MySQL inner query

Tags: mysql

Our product fits one or more models of several brands.

I want to generate a list of models of a user-selected brand that fits a single product.

```
SELECT ml.laser, pm.pistol_model_brand, pm.pistol_model_name
FROM pistol_model as pm
INNER JOIN model_laser as ml
ON pm.pistol_model_id = ml.model_id
WHERE pm.pistol_brand_id = :pistol_brand_id AND ml.laser LIKE 'GTO%'
ORDER BY ml.laser
```

The results (3 cols) show our product, brand, model. From here I want to, if possible, generate a list of these models that fits our product.

After struggling for too many hours, I am not sure if this is possible, or if I need to reconstruct my tables.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a double check on your logic for the first join condition. Is the pistol model id really the same as the laser model id?

```
SELECT 
    ml.laser
   ,pm.pistol_model_brand
   ,pm.pistol_model_name
FROM pistol_model as pm
INNER JOIN model_laser as ml
ON pm.pistol_model_id = ml.model_id
and pm.pistol_brand_id = ml.pistol_brand_id
WHERE 
    ml.laser LIKE 'GTO%'
ORDER BY 
    ml.laser
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, they are the same. Query works. Need to learn if I can get all pistol model matches to our laser model.